# Python argparse difficulties

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a command-line argument parser for my program using the builtin Python module `argparse`. I want the user to be able to either run my program normally, or to run a demo. To run a demo requires a demo number, which would be a command line argument. So, basically, the command-line arguments are allowed to be in one of these formats.

- `python3 blah.py normal`
- `python3 blah.py demo <demo#>`

How do I allow the user to use either of the options, but not both at the same time? Also, how do I make the demo number required when using the demo option but not when using the normal option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mutually exclusive group (I have changed arguments to -demo number and -normal):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-demo', action='store',
                    dest='demonum',
                    help='demo execution')
group.add_argument('-normal', action='store_true',
                    help='normal execution')
parsed = parser.parse_args()
print(parsed.demonum)
print(parsed.normal)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, how do I make it so that using neither option is illegal?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 even if you don't pass any arguments or 1 of the argument ,that is valid.only when you use both arguments then it will say invalid `python.exe d:\arguments.py -normal -demo 3`

Comment: Yes. I'm asking how to require the user to use one (and exactly one) of the arguments in the mutually exclusive group.